# Armature deforming in strange way

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting

I am very new to Blender so this might be a dumb question, but here goes.

I am creating this character for a game (very simple character) and when weight painting the arms it bends in a strange way (see pictures).

Does anyone know how I could fix this in the best way possible?
Thanks.

[image: Deformed part marked in blue]

[image]

Comment: first of all, put the Armature modifier above the Subsurf, and also enable its Preserve Volume option

Comment: possibly scaled bone